# Change pdflatex default paper size when installed using MacPorts

Tags: pdftex, texlive, paper-size, tlmgr, macports

I have used MacPorts to install TexLive on a MacBook Pro running MacOS 11.5.2

How do I change the default paper size for `pdflatex`?  Is there a way to do it without scrapping the MacPorts install for something else?

I understand that the standard approach is to run `texconfig paper letter`; but, I don't have `tlmgr` installed.  (It doesn't appear to come with the port.)

Is there a way to install `tlmgr` --- or perhaps a different config tool --- that will work with my existing TexLive installation?

Comment: For MacTeX, you have `TeX Live Utility`. See [this link](http://www.tug.org/mactex/)

Comment: @Bernard: This isn't MacTeX. Also, TeX Live Utility is a GUI to tlmgr.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: It seems I misunderstood, sorry. Does that mean that TeX Live Utility won't work?

Comment: @Bernard: If his distribution doesn't have tlmgr it won't work. On the other hand, I don't know if it's really TeX Live if it doesn't have tlmgr.